# Is dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...) necessary in this case?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I came across this piece of code, and I can't quite figure out why the author did this. Take a look at this code:

```
someMethodStandardMethodUsingABlock:^() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:"notif" object:nil];
    });
}];
```

I have a method with a completion block, and in this block a notification has to be posted. I don't quite understand why the `dispatch_async` on the main queue is necessary in this case. The block will already be run on the main thread, and even if it wasn't I don't think it would really matter would it? I would simply have written this:

```
someMethodStandardMethodUsingABlock:^() {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:"notif" object:nil];
}];
```

And it does work in my testing.

If you can help me shed some light on this, I'd really appreciate it!

Matt

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These 2 sentences from the NSNotificationCenter Class Reference suggest a couple of possible reasons:

> A notification center delivers notifications to observers
>   synchronously. In other words, the postNotification: methods do not
>   return until all observers have received and processed the
>   notification.

...

> In a multithreaded application, notifications are always delivered in
>   the thread in which the notification was posted, which may not be the
>   same thread in which an observer registered itself.

So perhaps (a) the author doesn't want the code to block until all observers have processed the notification, and/or (b) he wants to ensure that the observer methods run on the main thread.

Comment: Thank David, b seems to fit in my case. The docs don't seem to specify, but does it matter if the notification is sent on a different thread that the one the observer registered? By this I mean is the observer still reached

Comment: Yes, the observer will still receive the notification even if its sent on a different thread.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to run methods that fire some execution asynchronously and return right away. E.g. some of the `AppDelegate` 'key' methods like `applicationDidBecomeActive`, or `applicationDidEnterBackground`, need to be executed and return quickly so the OS doesn't kill your app.

I don't know if that is the case of your question, but it is a possible explanation of the usage of `dispatch_async`.